# os.OpenFile with O_CREATE flag throws no such file or directory

Tags: go

I'm trying to open a log file with os package using os.OpenFile function, which should with proper flag create file if such file does not exists. But it returns non nil error: No such file or directory. BTW I'm using linux and go 1.6. Log file opening happens in init function. Heres my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

// Structs holds server configuration data from config json.
type serverConfiguration struct {
    port                    string
    logFileName             string
    sessionStorePhrase      string
    resourceFilesPath       string
    resourceFilesPathPrefix string
}

// Server global variables.
var (
    serverConfig serverConfiguration
    logFile      *os.File
    router       *mux.Router
    sessionStore *sessions.CookieStore
)

func init() {
    // temporary variables.
    var (
        configFile                                   *os.File
        serverConfErr, configDecodingErr, logFileErr error
    )

    // Loads json config file.
    configFile, serverConfErr = os.Open("server-conf.json")
    defer configFile.Close()

    if serverConfErr != nil {
        log.Fatal("SERVER-CONFIG-ERROR: ", serverConfErr)
    }

    // Decodes json to serverConfig struct.
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(configFile)
    serverConfig = serverConfiguration{}
    configDecodingErr = decoder.Decode(&serverConfig)

    if configDecodingErr != nil {
        log.Fatal("CONFIGURATION-DECODING-ERROR: ", configDecodingErr)
    }

    // Opens log file in app root directory.
    logFile, logFileErr = os.OpenFile(serverConfig.logFileName, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)

    if logFileErr != nil {
        log.Fatal("LOG-FILE-ERROR: ", logFileErr)
    }

    // Creates session store.
    sessionStore = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte(serverConfig.sessionStorePhrase))
}

// Home page handler.
func homePageHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(writer, "asdasdasdasd")
}

func main() {
    defer logFile.Close()
    router = mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(false)
    resourceFileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir(serverConfig.resourceFilesPath))
    router.PathPrefix(serverConfig.resourceFilesPathPrefix).Handler(http.StripPrefix(serverConfig.resourceFilesPathPrefix, resourceFileServer))

    router.HandleFunc("/", homePageHandler)

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:    serverConfig.port,
        Handler: router,
    }

    log.Println("Server listening on port ", serverConfig.port)
    server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is most likely that the path you want to create your file in doesn't exist. it will create the logfile, but not the parent directories if they don't exist.
To create the necessary directory structure, you could use [`os.MkdirAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#MkdirAll)

Comment: the file path is logFile.txt

Comment: I ran your code. the issue I can see is that your config struct only has non-exported field (starting with lower-case letters) therefore the json package can't see them.

Comment: Yeah figured that out already repaired that its working now. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that json serverConfiguration had no values because it was not exported it needs to be like this:

```
// ServerConfiguration structs holds server configuration data from config json.
type ServerConfiguration struct {
    Port                    string `json:"port"`
    LogFileName             string `json:"logFileName"`
    SessionStorePhrase      string `json:"sessionStorePhrase"`
    ResourceFilesPath       string `json:"resourceFilesPath"`
    ResourceFilesPathPrefix string `json:"resourceFilesPathPrefix"`
}
```